# Adding a static additional p tag to dynamic object on one page through script

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://www.baptistjax.com/services/brain-and-spine/stroke-and-cerebrovascular-care  "this is the page I am adding the script in the side column googlemap under phone number info"

```
<script>
$("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5").append("<p>International Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
</script>
```

Ok this ended up working correctly! It inserts the additional copy directly after the last object within the dynamic object so that the outer container div border expands with this added.

Comment: I am unsure why this is not working? I am adding this additional info to a dynamic generated object on the page, for this page only. Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you running this code in a document.ready handler? Assuming it's at the top of the page or in the `<head>` then the DOM won't be ready when you try to access it

Comment: @AprilSmallwood have you checked the selector if you correctly selected your target element? can you try `console.log($("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5")` and see if it renders the correct element / not undefined?

Comment: I found the issue. This one worked >                                                 
       <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Render the international patients info within the google map content tab */
        $("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5").append("<p>International Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You `.append()` is missing an opening quote `"`.

```
$("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5").append(:international Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
```

Should be

```
$("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5").append(":international Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
```

Comment: OP has edited to include the quote. It seems to have just been a typo in the question

Comment: I am sorry that was a copy error I have it as I have it implemented now

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a double quote on the append, it should be

```
$("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5").append(":international Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
```

Comment: OP has edited to include the quote. It seems to have just been a typo in the question

Comment: I am sorry that was a copy error I have it as I have it implemented now

Answer (score 0):

These are a several reasons this may not be working.

First, wrap your code in a "ready" function.

```
// this is a jquery ready function
$(function() {
    $("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5").append(":international Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
});
```

Second, put your script after the script which generate the other dynamic content.

Third, if the dynamic content is being loaded asynchronously, you'll need to set a timeout that keeps checking for the dynamic element until it exists, then it can append your content and stop looking.

```
$(function() {
    function findElement() {
        var el = $("#sidebar div.find-tabs ul li .block.marginB5");

        // if the element exists, append
        if (el.length > 0) {
            el.append(":international Patients:<br />904.399.6518 (ext 164)</p>");
        }
        // otherwise, try again in 200 milliseconds
        else {
            setTimeout(findElement, 200);
        }
    }
    // start searching for the element
    findElement();
});
```